# Jenkins plugin for sequential check

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I have a below scenario

Parent Job triggers Job B and Job B triggers Job C and Job C triggers D in sequence irrespective of whether the child jobs (B,C,D) are failure or success.

What I want to achive is only after the Job B,Job C,Job D is success and JOB E should be triggered .If by chance any of the child jobs (B,C,D) failes then the final Job E should not be triggered.

How shall I go about this ?Any plugin is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select *Trigger only if build is stable*.

You may also be interested in using the Workflow plugin (as in your `jenkins-workflow` tag, perhaps accidental) to orchestrate the whole system programmatically:

```
build 'B'
build 'C'
build 'D'
build 'E'
```

Comment: Thanks Glick.But I want the JOB E to trigger only once and it should check  the all the upstream jobs(B,C,D) to be success only then it should trigger the JOB E

Comment: That is exactly what the above script does.